# how to pass body to http delete method in angular 2

Tags: angular

```
obj={
    "candidateFeedbackQuestionInfoId": 8
};

jsonobj=JSON.stringify(this.obj);

return this.http.delete(this.feebackUrl,this.jsonobj).map(this.extractData);
```

if we pass body to delete it will throw type mismatch error, any help would be great

Answer (score 8):

The second argument to `delete` is a [`RequestOptionsArgs`](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptionsArgs). So you could do

```
this.http.delete(this.feebackUrl,{ body: this.jsonobj })
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete should typically use Request or URL parameters. Ideally an identifier of the object should be sufficient to delete an object. If you are doing anything more, i would recommend using post

Here is the Angular2 code for delete API call

```
this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
return this.http.delete('/rest/batch/' + audit.timestamp.toString(), this.options)
          .map(res => res.json());
```

On the server side, which is using Express, you can receive the call as follows

```
app.delete('/rest/batch/:id', function(req, res) {
  objectStore.removeBatchObject(req, res); // your code to perform operation
});
```

Alternatively you could pass more parameters in RequestOptions object, if at all you have to bypass the typical structure of DELETE REST API

Answer (score 0):

`RequestOptionsArgs` and `RequestOptions` are deprecated with HttpClient by now. You can send JSON data with DELETE method with abstract request method like this:

```
deleteItem(id: string) {
    return this.http
      .request('DELETE', API_URL + '/item', { params: { sessionId: "12345"}, body: {itemId: id}})
      .map(this.getResponseData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

`params` will be query strings and `body` will be JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this example :

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const headersJson = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 this.http.request("delete", APPLICATION_HOST + '/employee/delete/', 
 {  
      headers : headersJson,

      body : "{empId : 123, empname : 'jerwo'}"
  })
  .subscribe(
        res => {
     // Ok
  },

  err => 
  {

     // Error ops   

  });
```